# Отображение .doc в своем приложении на андроид

Tags: doc, android, java

Пытаюсь сделать приложение, в котором пользователь сможет читать документы со своего телефона на андроиде. Есть ли библиотеки, желательно бесплатные, которые помогут в этом?

Answer (score 1):

У меня, вроде как, вот этот способ работает. Метод сей получает строку из файла, путь к которому передаётся в неё.

```
public static String getStringFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception
    {
        File fl = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fl);
        String ret = convertStreamToString(fin);
        //Make sure you close all streams.
        fin.close();
        return ret;
    }
```

Вызывать:

```
try
{
 String strFromDocFile= КЛАСС_ГДЕ_ОПИСАН_МЕТОД.getStringFromFile(ПУТЬ_К_ФАЙЛУ);
} catch (Exception e)
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Далее передать полученную строку в текстовое поле. Должно сработать.